# Mongoose retrieve array of objects. For each object, I only want two properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am just practicing Mongoose with JavaScript.

I have this mongoose schema below:

```
const item = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  qty: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  costPrice: Number
});

const supplySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  items: [item]
});

const Supply = mongoose.model("Supply", supplySchema);
```

Right now I just want to retrieve an array of `item` using mongoose.

I wish my data to look like this:

```
[
  {
    "name" : "Lemon",
    "qty" : 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Sugar",
    "qty": 5
  }
]
```

But right now the data I get back looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5e4df1c1d48926133879f650",
    "costPrice": 0.4,
    "name": "Sugar",
    "qty": 5
  }
]
```

I tried writing such a code below but it does not work:

```
const supplyDoc = await Supply.findOne();
const supplies = await supplyDoc.items.select("-_id");
return supplies;
```

I thought I could somehow use projection on the items and specify that I don't want the _id property for each object in the array. But my code does not work. Is there a mongoose or MongoDB method I can utilize? Or do I have to use javascript to manipulate the array?

Hope to hear some advice. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use Model.find() instead of Model.findOne() if you want an array of items.

And yes you can use the projection parameter to select the fields you want.

So

```js
const supplies = await Supply.find({}, "name qty").exec()
```

Edit: So apparently you need to specifically exclude the _id field, you can do this using `-` as prefix.

```js
const supplies = await Supply.find({}, "-_id name qty").exec()
```

Comment: I have modified to follow your code. So the retrieved data is :

```

[
  {
    "name": "Sugar",
    "qty": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Ice",
    "qty": 5,
    "_id": "5e4e005a96944c0c1c46dbc1"
  }
]

```

but the situation now is that each `item` has its own `_id` and the `_id` is retrieved. How do I go about 'removing' this property ?

Comment: Add `-_id` in the projection string

Answer (score 0):

Try to do in this way

```
  let supplies= await models.Supplier.find( { }, { name:1,qty:1,_id: 0 } )
```